# split string c# based on math operator

Tags: c#, split

(Calculator program)count in one step with math basic order

if there is a string = "5+2*6/9"(which is user input) how to get number 2 and 6?
i've been trying with split but if there is no '+' it fail :(

here is my code atm

```
 string[] a = kalimat.Split('*');
                        string[] a1 = a[0].Split('+');
                        string[] a2 = a1[a1.Count() - 1].Split('-');
                        string[] b1 = a[1].Split('+');
                        string[] b2 = b1[0].Split('-');
                        ang1 = a2[a2.Count() - 1];
                        ang2 = b2[0];
                        angka1 = Convert.ToDouble(ang1);
                        angka2 = Convert.ToDouble(ang2);
                        hasil = angka1 * angka2;
```

any idea guys?

Comment: Do you hava a pattern to split for all the time? For example; split with `*` and get last character of the first item and get the first character of the second item?

Comment: What is your purpose? you want to calculate to get the result from formula?

Comment: My purpose is to make a calculator like windows 7,so all in one text and  my program count it

Comment: Sorry i mean like a google calculator where after all have been inputed,my program count it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're input expression is always in the form: "[some number]+[first value you want to return]*[second value you want to return]" then this should work for you:

```
var reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\d\+(\d)\*(\d)");
var result = reg.Match("5+2*6/9");
var first = result.Groups[1];
var second = result.Groups[2];
```

You can of course tweak the regular expression search pattern to suit your needs.

Comment: umm,its actually user input so its varies

Comment: well, you know that's a perfect example of information you should have included in your question.  Most of us are not mind readers.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing arbitrary mathematical expression is not a trivial task. If this isn't a homework that require you to do the parsing by hand, I would suggest to find a library for doing the task, like [NCalc](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/) for example.

You can install it from [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NCalc-Edge/1.4.0.9), and use the following simple code :

```
var kalimat = "5+2*6/9";
var hasil = new NCalc.Expression(kalimat).Evaluate();
Console.WriteLine(hasil);
```

Selamat mencoba :)

Comment: wow thats seem so simple..although too bad this is a homework :( so no library just basic split or any string function..