# Split string at particular characters (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

What I want to do is to split an array and  then put the character which i split at into another element 
i.e. 
 `string text = "1*5+89-43&99"` 
 should become 
 `string[] textsplit = ["1","*","5","+","89","-","43","&","99"]` (it must be a string)
and I will supply the characters to be left in seperate elements

Comment: Just a question: how are you able to determine there are 4 elements in this string? `-43&99`, and not 3 or 2?

Comment: What have you tried to solve your problem, where is your code?

Comment: What would the results be for the input of `"-1+-2*-10.1*.1"`?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: I don't think you articulated the last bit correctly but I reckon [RegEx](https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex) will help you solve your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [split string c# based on math operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578062/split-string-c-sharp-based-on-math-operator) Accepted answer shows how to use `Regex` for that

Comment: If you are using MoreLinq, consider starting with `var input = "1*5+89-43&99";
        var results = input.GroupAdjacent(char.IsDigit);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", results.Select(z => new string(z.ToArray())).ToList()));`. This will output `1,*,5,+,89,-,43,&,99` (the `string.Join` is putting the `,` there - remove it to remove the `,`). Basically you split on whether the digit is a number or not.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski no as it doesn't show the *

Comment: @Stefan I don't know, it should keep splitting till the end, for loop maybe?

Comment: @mjwills ['-','1', '+','-','2','*','-','10.1','*','.1']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following code snippet:

```
        string text  = "1*1*5+89-43&33";
        List<string> textsplit = new List<string>();
        foreach(var match in Regex.Matches(text, @"([*+/\-)(])|([0-9]+)"))
        {
            textsplit.Add(match.ToString());
        }
```

Result added as an image.

[image: Result will be like this]

Comment: Thanks! and how can I check for more symbols i.e. `^` as I'm not familiar with RegEx

Comment: Can you specify an example for the above scenario? @OmerHijazi Did you meant this -  string text = "^1*1*5+89-43&33"; ?

Comment: e.g. "1^5" or something like that and also how can I include decimal numbers i.e. "1*2^7-33.1" should become ['1','*','2','^','7','-','33.1'] @ScareCrow nvm I changed to ([*+/\-^())(])|([0-9.]+) so now it can also show parantheses in seperate elements and decimal too. kinda getting the hang of it

Comment: Hope you got the answer. @OmerHijazi @"([^*+/\-)(])|([0-9]+)" this is for handling ^.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [`string.IndexOfAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexofany?view=netcore-3.1).

Simply keep looking for the next index of any of the separators. When you find a separator, add the text between it and the last separator to your results, then look for the next separator.

```
string input = "1*1*5+89-43&33";
var separators = new[] { '+', '-', '*', '/', '&' };
var result = new List<string>();

int index;
int lastIndex = 0;
while ((index = input.IndexOfAny(separators, lastIndex)) != -1)
{
    // Add the text before the separator, if there is any
    if (index - lastIndex > 0)
    {
        result.Add(input.Substring(lastIndex, index - lastIndex));
    }
    
    // Add the separator itself
    result.Add(input[index].ToString());

    lastIndex = index + 1;  
}

// Add any text after the last separator
if (lastIndex < input.Length)
{
    result.Add(input.Substring(lastIndex));
}
```

Comment: @OmerHijazi You'll need `using System.Collections.Generic;` of course. Here it is working: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4YlGlm

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic and naive implementation that I beliewe will do what you want:

```
public static List<string> SplitExpression(string expression)
{
    var parts = new List<string>();
    
    bool isNumber(char c) => c == '.' || (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
    bool isOperator(char c) => !isNumber(c);

    int index = 0;
    while (index < expression.Length)
    {
        char c = expression[index];
        index++;

        if (isNumber(c))
        {
            int numberIndex = index - 1;
            while (index < expression.Length && isNumber(expression[index]))
                index++;
            parts.Add(expression.Substring(numberIndex, index - numberIndex));
        }
        else
            parts.Add(c.ToString());
    }

    // move unary signs into following number
    index = 0;
    while (index < parts.Count - 1)
    {
        bool isSign = parts[index] == "-" || parts[index] == "+";
        bool isFirstOrFollowingOperator = index == 0 || isOperator(parts[index - 1][0]);
        bool isPriorToNumber = isNumber(parts[index + 1][0]);
        
        if (isSign && isFirstOrFollowingOperator && isPriorToNumber)
        {
            parts[index + 1] = parts[index] + parts[index + 1];
            parts.RemoveAt(index);
        }
        else
            index++;
    }
    return parts;
}
```

Example input: `"-1+-2*-10.1*.1"`, and output:

```
-1 
+ 
-2 
* 
-10.1 
* 
.1
```